# Passing command once logged through aws ssm start session in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to pass "sudo su - < user >" command once i logged though AWS CLI using aws ssm?

> aws ssm start-session --target "instance ID" ??????? "sudo su - < user >"

Is there any way? Passing as parameters or something?

Comment: Nah, you need STS - SSM is the System Manager. . Try type `aws configure` and make sure you have created an IAM user with programmatic access, save the Access and Secret keys when you create the user to enter in the command when it prompts you

Comment: But this question doesn't make much sense. You need to SSH into a Linux box to execute that `sudo` command.

Comment: I need to pass some ubuntu command to remote instance as i log through aws ssm start session?

Comment: say I need to pass "bash -l -o vi" to remote instance as i log through aws ssm start session?

Comment: Nah you don't login through SSM, you're probably confusing that with STS or getting a value from parameter store in SSM. To SSH into an EC2 is trivial, then you run the Sudo su command.

Comment: I understand now, if you want to execute a command on a bunch of servers you can do that via SSM, but I think you want to `ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ip` as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get into an EC2 instance from the command line without SSH. Whenever you can avoid using SSH, and use more cloud-native approaches such as System Manager's Session Manager, that is recommended.

[The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/start-session.html) says:

> **Example 1: To start a Session Manager session**
>
> This start-session example establishes a connection with an instance
> for a Session Manager session. Note that this interactive command
> requires the Session Manager plugin to be installed on the client
> machine making the call.
>
> ```
> aws ssm start-session \
>     --target "i-1234567890abcdef0"
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Starting session with SessionId: Jane-Roe-07a16060613c408b5
> ```

So you can get into your EC2 instance that way, and then enter `"sudo su - < user >"`.

However, passing in parameters with the `aws ssm start-session` AWS CLI command is currently not supported, as that same documentation page says:

> --parameters (map)
>
> **Reserved for future use.**
>
> key -> (string)
>
> value -> (list)
>
> (string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ***send_command***, not start session

Python code example:

```
def send_command(self, instanceID: str) -> str:
    ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
    response = ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=[instanceID],
        DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
        Parameters={'commands': ['sudo su - < user >']}, 
        Comment='test comment',
        TimeoutSeconds=60, )
    command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
   
    waiter = ssm_client.get_waiter('command_executed')
    waiter.wait(
        CommandId=command_id,
        InstanceId=instanceID,
        )
 
    output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
        CommandId=command_id,
        InstanceId=instanceID,
        )
    return output
```